# Visual Studio XML File Editor Lowercase

Tags: xml, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2013

I'm editing cshtml in Visual Studio (with a .cshtml file extension). I auto format or paste in some xml (which triggers an auto format) and Visual Studio lowercases all my xml attributes (so theAttribute > theattribute).

This is wrong. How can I fix? I don't see a relevant option under Tools > Options.

Comment: Are there any new solutions to this problem I couldn't use Twilio properly because of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605151/twiml-app-unexpected-end-of-call-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-respon/30622501?noredirect=1#comment49361229_30622501

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found a way to configure this behavior, but as workaround you can explicitly select editor to be used with *.cshtml files and then it works properly.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension

[image]

P.S. It looks like there were plans for HTML (Razor) text editor settings in a separate node, but I don't see it in release of VS 2013. See [HTML Editing Features in Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/html-editing-features-in-visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx)

Also I saw that Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML (Web Forms) -> Formatting has options which specifically mention the behavior you are getting.

Comment: Will this break intellisense?

Comment: I still saw code suggestions, but haven't verified deeply enough. Btw, you can try with different editors

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try this:

- Options

  - Text

    - Editor

      - HTML

        - Advanced

          - Format on paste: **False**
          - Enable validation: **False**

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->XML->Formatting
(*) Preserve manual attribute formatting

also, uncheck the other settings.  Do you have Resharper or something else that could be affecting it as well?

Comment: resharper...could be that? already checked relevant options in there and tried disabling but same result

Answer (score 0):

Try
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Html -> Advanced 
then set "XHTML coding style" false
and set "Format on paste" false