# TwiML App unexpected end of call: Cannot find the declaration of element 'response'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

I created [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=stackdocsupdate) application and set Voice request URL the web deployed ASP.NET-MVC aplication action method: http://voiceapp-001-site1.myasp.net/voice

This action method is invoked when somebody goes to the URL posted above:

```
 public ActionResult Voice() {

            Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

            // put a phone number you've verified with Twilio to use as a caller ID number
            string callerId = Settings.TwilioNumber;

            // put your default Twilio Client name here, for when a phone number isn't given
            string number = "jenny";

            // get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
            if (Request["PhoneNumber"] != null) {
                number = Request["PhoneNumber"];
            }

            // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
            // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
            string numberOrClient;
            var m = Regex.Match(number, @"^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$");
            if (m.Success) {
                numberOrClient = string.Format("<Number>{0}</Number>", number);
            } else {
                numberOrClient = string.Format("<Client>{0}</Client>", number);
            }
            ViewBag.CallerId = callerId;
            ViewBag.NumberOfClient = numberOrClient;
            return View();
        }
```

The `Voice` view looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <dial callerid="@ViewBag.CallerId">
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.NumberOfClient)
    </dial>
</response>
```

Then I try to make test call:

[image]

but after 13 seconds call is automatically terminated and In the error log I get:

```
Notification SID NOe85ffe80dfc52e81f942a7414c9f7c9c
Warning 12200 Schema validation warning
Description Cannot find the declaration of element 'response'.
```

But below in the Body section I can see the element `response`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Twilio developer evangelist here.

Can you try modifying your view to look like this instead?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="@ViewBag.CallerId">
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.NumberOfClient)
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Remember XML is case-sensitive, so the casing in your XML tags actually matter. Also, I would suggest using the [Twilio.TwiML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.TwiML/) helper library. With that, you can get your XML generated for you with the right casing, and avoiding typos altogether.

Here's how you'd do it:

```
var twiml = new TwilioResponse();
var dialAttributes = new {callerId = "48326304351"};

var dial = twiml.Dial("+15555555555", dialAttributes);
return TwiML(dial);
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort.As you advised I corrected my XML to this version: http://voiceapp-001-site1.myasp.net/voice but now I get: schema validation warning `Attribute 'callerid' is not allowed to appear in element 'Dial'.` I will try to use Twiml to generate XML for me.

Comment: Hey, again another case of wrong case used. I just updated my example so callerId is not all lowercase

Comment: Thank you. I can't safely paste XML into cshtml in Visual Studio 2013 because it runs auto formatting which changes the letter cases(to lower case). As I see it is common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961151/visual-studio-xml-file-editor-lowercase Could you please show how to achieve the same thing using `Twilio.TwilML` as I can find only Raw XML examples on /www.twilio.com

Comment: @Yoda updated the answer with the generator for Twiml